# Standalone webapp and Browser scrollbars

Tags: google-apps-script

**EDIT (last ! :-) :** A workaround to this is putting the whole UI in an absolutePanel (thx megabyte1024).
It's not perfect since I cannot have a background color in the whole display area but it's at least much more confortable. (link to online test app is updated with this new version) and screen capture of the final version... much better :-)

[image]

---

I have a standalone webapp written in GAS that has a scrollPanel, the whole UI is rather small and occupies only a part of a (even small) display area in the browser window.

What bothers me is that I always have both an horizontal and a vertical scrollbar in the browser window and it interferes with the UI content when I use a mouse or a trackpad to scroll my scrollpanel in the UI window...
So, my question is : is there a way to avoid this, to tell the browser that there is no need to add scrollbars or to define a smaller "webapp area" ?

note that the size of these scroll bars are fully independent from the UI panel size as long as this last one is smaller than the browser window.

Here is a screen capture to illustrate what I'm saying (I do understand that it's a detail but it makes the use of this app sometimes just uncomfortable ;-)   Here is also a link to a [public version of the app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby1CQyMYZslTV4lRfjjLNWXiDIr2REiyV8PS3xfQ7ORFW5ONpti/exec).
[image]

Another detail I'd like to solve is the font color in the upper part of this UI : these are textBoxes that I set to 'read only' because I don't want them to be editable (it would give the illusion that the user could modify data which is not the case) and a side effect of this read only status is that fonts are "greyed" ... is there some way to avoid that while keeping the same aspect (except color) on this 'false table' ?

**EDIT :** found the second question about text color : `.setStyleAttribute('color','#000000')` as simple as that... too stupid from me not to have found it earlier ;-)

**NOTE 2** *: interestingly, UI designed with the GUI builder do not suffer the same problem ...*

**EDIT2** :here is the code of the doGet part (modified to run without functionality but to showup):

```
var key='0AnqSFd3iikE3dFV3ZlF5enZIV0JQQ0c1a3dWX1dQbGc'
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key)
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
var idx = 0
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
var len = data.length;
var scrit = ['All fields','Name','Lastname','Postal Adress','ZIP code','City','Country','email','phone#']
 //public version


function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("BrowseList Test")
       .setHeight(420).setWidth(800).setStyleAttribute("background-color","beige").setStyleAttribute('padding','20');
    var title = app.createHTML('<B>DATABASE User Interface</B>').setStyleAttribute('color','#888888');
    app.add(title);
    var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(750,150)
    var vpanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
    var cell = new Array();
    var cellWidth = [45,135,150,250,50,100]
    var row = new Array();
    var cHandler = app.createServerHandler('showpicked').addCallbackElement(scroll);
    for(vv=0;vv<15;++vv){
      row[vv]=app.createHorizontalPanel();
      vpanel.add(row[vv]);
       for(hh=0;hh<cellWidth.length;++hh){
        cell[hh+(vv)*cellWidth.length]=app.createTextBox().setWidth(cellWidth[hh]+"").setTitle('Click to show below')
        .setReadOnly(true).setId((hh+vv*cellWidth.length)+'').addClickHandler(cHandler).setStyleAttribute('background','#eeeeff').setStyleAttribute('color','#000000');
        row[vv].add(cell[hh+(vv)*cellWidth.length])
        }
      }
app.add(scroll.add(vpanel))
// Initial populate
      var resindex = new Array()     
    for(vv=0;vv<15;++vv){
        resindex.push(vv+1)
       for(hh=0;hh<cellWidth.length;++hh){
         var rowpos=vv+1+idx
         var cellpos = hh+vv*cellWidth.length
        cell[cellpos].setValue(data[rowpos][hh]);
        }
      }
  var rHandler = app.createServerHandler('refresh');
//
  var slist = app.createListBox().setName('critere').setId('slist').addClickHandler(rHandler);
    for(nn=0;nn<scrit.length;++nn){
      slist.addItem(scrit[nn]);
      }
  var search = app.createTextBox().setName('search').setId('search').setTitle('becomes yellow if no match is found');
  var modeS = app.createRadioButton('chkmode','strict').setId('chkmodes').addClickHandler(rHandler);
  var modeG = app.createRadioButton('chkmode','global').setValue(true).setId('chkmodeg').addClickHandler(rHandler);
  var letter = app.createRadioButton('show','letter').setValue(true).setId('letter').addClickHandler(rHandler);
  var raw = app.createRadioButton('show','raw data').setId('raw').addClickHandler(rHandler);
  var index = app.createHTML('found/'+len).setId('index').setStyleAttribute('color','#aaaaaa');
  var grid = app.createGrid(2,10).setWidth('750');
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('search'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, search);
  grid.setWidget(1, 2, modeS);
  grid.setWidget(1, 3, modeG);
  grid.setWidget(1, 5, slist);
  grid.setWidget(1, 6, app.createLabel('show mode'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 7, letter);
  grid.setWidget(1, 8, raw);
  grid.setWidget(1, 9, index);
  app.add(grid);

  var hidden = app.createHidden('hidden').setId('hidden').setValue(resindex.toString());
  cHandler.addCallbackElement(grid).addCallbackElement(scroll).addCallbackElement(hidden);
  var result = app.createRichTextArea().setPixelSize(745,160).setId('result')
  .setStyleAttribute('background','white').setStyleAttribute('font-family',"Arial, sans-serif")
  .setStyleAttribute('font-size','small');
  result.setHTML('test ui');
  app.add(result).add(hidden);
  var sHandler = app.createServerHandler('searchH').addCallbackElement(grid).addCallbackElement(scroll);
  search.addKeyUpHandler(sHandler);
  rHandler.addCallbackElement(grid).addCallbackElement(scroll);
  slist.addChangeHandler(rHandler);

return app
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution to get rid of the scroll bar is to use an intermediate `Absolute` panel. The following code has the scroll bars.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createScrollPanel().setSize('100%', '100%');
  var content = app.createButton('Scroll Bars').setSize('100%', '100%');
  panel.setWidget(content);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

And the code bellow has no the scroll bars

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createScrollPanel().setSize('100%', '100%');
  var subPanel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setSize('100%', '100%');
  var content = app.createButton('No Scroll Bars').setSize('100%', '100%');
  subPanel.add(content);
  panel.setWidget(subPanel);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I tried to apply to my code but it doesn't seem to work... I posted the doGet part as an edit in my question, if ever you feel 'courageous' could you suggest a possible structure ?(I posted my original version since my attempts were unsuccessful ;-) (and I'd understand you if you don't feel like going into this!!!) thx anyway

Comment: @Sergeinsas. Tried to use your script. There is the `Document 0AnqSFd3iikE3dFV3ZlF5enZIV0JQQ0c1a3dWX1dQbGc is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)` error message.

Comment: ooops, sorry, I forgot to share it... I'll do it now ;-)

Comment: Hi, I finally got it to work with your suggestion, see updated question. thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

when embedding a HTMLService web app inside a Google Site, it looks like the iFrame gadget has to be about 50 pixels larger than the app height for the vertical scroll bar to disappear. Assuming same thing applies to UiApp.